# (HTML/CSS) Text in a button doesn't show itself in certain browsers

Tags: html, css

As I said, depending on what browser I'm using, the button varies for some reason.
Here's the code I'm using right now-
HTML-

```
<input type="button" id="submitButton" onclick="generateLink()" value="Go" />
```

CSS-

```
#submitButton {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #8373e6;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid #8373e6;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #9c9c9c67;
  width: min-content;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#submitButton:hover {
  background-color: #6b5ebd;
}

#submitButton:active {
  background-color: #554a97;
}
```

Whenever I look this up on the live server on my Windows PC (on both Firefox and Chrome), it looks the way I want it to. But when I deploy the test site on Firebase and check it out on my mobile phone (iPhone with Safari Browser), The text "Go" is gone and all I can see is a flat, text-less button.
I have also tried changing the `<input>` tag to a `<button>` tag, adding a `display: block;` and a bunch of other stuff but it doesnt seem to work.

Any idea why this could be happening?
Please and thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to use [css normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) before all. It would make things more consistent.

Comment: Try not specifying any custom font, and see if that changes things.

Comment: The only thing that could explain that is that you have additional CSS or JavaScript that is causing it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using anchor element ?

```
<a href='' id="submitButton" onclick="generateLink()" value="Go">Go </a>

a{
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #8373e6;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid #8373e6;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #9c9c9c67;
  width: min-content;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #6b5ebd;
  cursor:pointer;
}

a:active {
  background-color: #554a97;
}
```